I'm facing this error while running my Flutter project on my device. PLease hellp me to resolve it
(https://i.sstatic.net/wiN5tJhY.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/yrqE5Uc0.png)
This is the error I'm facing
I tried re-installing ANdroid studio.
Rechecked the paths of the files.
Also updated Sdk tools.
but none of them worked.
Please help me to resolve this error. My laptop has only one directory,i.e, C-Drive Is it because of that?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Also, the title of your post is nothing but useless noise. Please read [ask] for advice on writing a good title. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who sees it in a list of search results will know what it contains, and the title you have now says nothing at all descriptive.

You didnt accept the license agreements.
you can use flutter doctor --android-licenses command and
Then enter y to accept agreement.
